# Javascript equivalent for vbscript Now and Time()

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I want to convert vb script Now and Time() to javascript. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: What do they do? anyway just create a `new Date` and use it's methods.

Comment: I just searched on net, w3school says, Time -> The current system time, Now -> The current system date and time

Comment: Thanx gdoron, I have an idea now :) . I will find the answer and write here. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 3):

When you create a new [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) in JavaScript it is, by default, automatically created for the current time. You can then use the properties of the object to get information about the current date and time.

```
var date = new Date();
var d = date.day;
var m = date.month;
var y = date.year;
```

You can also use `date.value` for the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, if you need an exact value.

Answer (score 1):

### VBScript Now

```
document.write(Now)

Output
m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM
```

### JavaScript Equiv

```
var datetime = {
    d: new Date(),
    now: function () {
        return this.today() + " " + this.time();
    },
    time: function () {
        var ampm = this.d.getHours() > 11 ? "PM" : "AM";
        return this.d.getHours() + ":" + this.d.getMinutes() + ":" + this.d.getSeconds() + " " + ampm;
    },
    today: function () {
        var month = this.d.getMonth() + 1;
        return month + "/" + this.d.getDate() + "/" + this.d.getFullYear();
    }
};

console.log(datetime.now());
```

The **OP** mentioned a different dating format from what I was seeing while on my work machine. Now that I am home, I am getting a different value for VBScript's Now. I'll leave my original `datetime` object. It may be helpful one day for someone. But to get similar output from JavaScript, all you need is to assign a new date object and call it's `toString()` method. I'm seeing similar results right now:

#### In JavaScript

```
var now = (new Date()).toString();
console.log(now); // ATM: Fri Mar 1 22:17:40 PST 2013
```

#### Compared to VBS' Now

```
document.Write(Now) // ATM:Fri Mar 1 22:17:40 PST 2013
```

Comment: vb script now giving this kind of answer `Fri Mar 1 12:13:34 UTC+0530 2013`

Comment: plz visit this, http://jsbin.com/uqoray/2/edit and visit this page with IE http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_now.asp

Comment: Now that I am at home, it is the way you described. Interesting. Perhaps a system policy on my work network. In that case `console.log(datetime.d.toString())` or assign a variable has a `new Date()`. I'll update my answer.