# Javascript date format Jun 23, 2010 12:00 AM

Tags: javascript

How to make a format like this in javascript, using Date function:

```
Jun 23, 2010 12:00 AM
```

Comment: Please have a look at the right part of this page entitled "Related"

Comment: Related and/or duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151902/javascript-equivalent-for-vbscript-now-and-time/15152044#15152044
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605971/formatting-the-date-in-javascript?rq=1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/tqwEE/

```
var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

var date = new Date();

console.log(months[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getDate() + ", " + (date.getYear()+1900) + " " + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes());

//Example Output: Apr 28, 2013 20:47
```